# Pulsating style with CSS?

Tags: wordpress, css

My URL: http://www.infinite-possibility.com/

I was wondering how I could achieve a sort of "Pulsating" feel/effect when the home button on the ipad frame of my site is pushed.

Currently the way that it is setup that whole frame is one jpg with the button contained with the button contained in its own div.

Any ideas how i could do this? Im really just looking for any effect that could spice the feel up a bit.

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the relevant code.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want. Do you want it to glow when mouse hovers over? Only on mouse down? Actually pulsate, like an animation?

Comment: glow on mouse down.. animation would be cool, but id rather not use jQuery as we have already had issues with conflicting JS scripts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UI/Effects/Pulsate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate)
use this JQuery plugin for that effect